# Magento: show all the products of categories in the main menu. underneath each main category

Tags: php, magento

I have created a new store and added two products categories and products to each category. Now I want to show all the products in the main menu underneath each main category. This is the link to my store: http://mxcounters.com/promos/index.php/

And following is the link to my Navigation.php file:https://app.box.com/s/0d6mbaxan2akh4wlkcdgkdef7qb3ok2a

Comment: i have tried to fetch the products from each category but nothing is working for me.. i am just new..please help..

Comment: and i have tried some tutorials to over ride the renderCategoryitem function in Navigation.php by this one.
============
here is the file link to my over ride function
https://app.box.com/s/0d6mbaxan2akh4wlkcdgkdef7qb3ok2a

Answer (score 0):

Thank God.. I have done this by custom coding created the new custom blocks in the admin section and assigned these block to a megamenu. then created a new file with name featured.phtml and add the following code in it to fetch all the products from category by ID.
==============featured.phtml========================

here is the file: https://app.box.com/s/oklzeq8luf6hnol2m6sh93xwwwh3n2lb

then fetch each category into mega menu by block code.

{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"}}